# Saved image from JOGL 2 is all red

Tags: jogl

When I save an image in a JOGL 2 application, the image is rendered in different shades of red, rather than the expected colors.

Here is the code I use to save the image:

`AWTGLReadBufferUtil glReadBufferUtil = new AWTGLReadBufferUtil(gl.getGL2().getGLProfile(), false);
BufferedImage image = glReadBufferUtil.readPixelsToBufferedImage(gl.getGL2(), true);
ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);`

Any hints how to troubleshoot this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: It's probably a bug, please fill a bug report, provide a test case or indicate how to reproduce it with a test case already in JOGL and put your image into your bug report. As you don't give any information on the PNG file that you use, we can't reproduce it.

Comment: Hi Peter, what do you want to save exactly? The back buffer?